# Logging for multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, database-design

Lets say we have a client table for sports brands like nike and adidas.

```
+--------------+------------+
| Client Table |            |
+--------------+------------+
| Id           | ClientName |
| 1            | Nike       |
| 2            | Adidas     |
+--------------+------------+
```

We also record customer information and their preferred sport and fitness level. Sports and fitness level are used in dropdown lists.

```
+--------------+------------+
| Sports Table |            |
+--------------+------------+
| Id           | Name       |
| 1            | Basketball |
| 2            | Volleyball |
+--------------+------------+

+------------------+---------------+
| Fitnesslvl Table |               |
+------------------+---------------+
| Id               | Fitness Level |
| 1                | Beginner      |
| 2                | Intermediate  |
| 3                | Advance       |
+------------------+---------------+

+----------------+--------------+----------+----------------+
| Customer Table |              |          |                |
+----------------+--------------+----------+----------------+
| Id             | CustomerName | SportsId | FitnessLevelId |
| 1              | John         | 1        | 1              |
| 2              | Doe          | 2        | 3              |
+----------------+--------------+----------+----------------+
```

Then sports brands want to filter our customer via sports and fitness level. In this example nike wants all sports while adidas only wants customer interested in basketball. Likewise, nike wants customer in all fitness level while adidas only wants advanced fitness level.

```
+---------------+----------+----------+
| Sports Filter |          |          |
+---------------+----------+----------+
| Id            | ClientId | SportsId |
| 1             | 1        | 1        |
| 2             | 1        | 2        |
| 3             | 2        | 1        |
+---------------+----------+----------+

+-------------------+----------+--------------+
| Fitnesslvl Filter |          |              |
+-------------------+----------+--------------+
| Id                | ClientId | FitnessLvlId |
| 1                 | 1        | 1            |
| 2                 | 1        | 2            |
| 3                 | 1        | 3            |
| 4                 | 2        | 3            |
+-------------------+----------+--------------+
```

How can we handle logging in this case when we want to record failed filters for the sports and fitness level? I'm thinking of two options

1. Create different table for each failed filter. 
   -Sports Failed Filter
   -FitnessLevel Failed Filter

```
+----------------------+-------------+----------------+
| Sports Failed Filter |             |                |
+----------------------+-------------+----------------+
| Id                   | CustomerId  | SportsFilterId |
| 1                    | 1           | 2              |
| 2                    | 1           | 3              |
+----------------------+-------------+----------------+
```

However if we have 10 filters, this means we will also have 10 failed filters table. I think this is very difficult to maintain.

2. Instead of different table for dropdown values like sports and fitness level, we can create lookup table, and a single failedfilter table.
   I think the tradeoff is its not simple and there is no strict referential integrity.

Please let me know if you have different solution for this.

EDIT:
This filters are used in a backend application and the filtering logic is there. I dont plan to include this logic in the database as the query will be very complex and hard to maintain.

Comment: Maybe some table, in which you will store queries that returned zero rows? Then it would be easy to log such information placing this logic in trigger.

Comment: Why do you want to store this information? Every time you add a customer it will be invalidated...

Comment: @Nick this is used in reports. Very useful if you want to know which filters are failing and decide whether you want to expand the filter or not.

Comment: But you can generate it on the fly quite readily and know that the result is up-to-date....

Comment: create temp tables if you dont need this data in future, i.e. just for report purpose.

Comment: @Nick yes thats possible. But theres a possiblity that the result from the on the fly query will be different from the application's filter result. Also, still a lot of join and very complex query.

Comment: There are 2 ways where i think you can achieve this: 1st `SQL-Side`( **SQL Injection Risk** ) Create a Stored Procedure which will act as a wrapper over all your queries being executed, that takes the query and its parameters as `string` and executes them, here you can log the queries(*with filters*). 2nd you can handle that at your `client-side` where again a `wrapper` would be the one executing the queries and logging them as well(as mentioned by *Michał Turczyn*).

Comment: You can get the unmatched customers as counts in the *reports*.  I don't see why this information needs to be stored separately.